# How to connect the local repository to the remote repository？

Tags: git

I have previously connected to a remote repository account jackey-xiong, now that account is no longer needed, and now I connect to the new account and report an error,why?

[image]

Comment: The error says the repository cannot be accessed by your new account. Either move your repository to your new account or add your new account to access the repository.

Comment: Another option is to make your repo public. But I dont think this is what you want

Comment: If u want to change ur remote, use this command -> `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git`. `git remote add` is only to add when there is no upstream set already.

Comment: how to move my repository to my new account

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the credentials of the old account are not still cached by Git credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
# if you see manager-core

printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git-credential-manager-core erase
```

Repeat that line until you see a popup asking for your credentials: select "Cancel" then (do not enter your credentials)

> how to move my repository to my new account

Then create a new empty repository in your new account.
Type `git ls-remote https://github.com/<newAccount>/<newRepo>`: enter your new credentials then (using the new GitHub Account, and a [PAT as password](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

Finally, go to your local clone of the old repository:

```sh
cd /path/to/old/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<newAccount>/<newRepo>
git push --mirror
```

You can then resume working on the new repo, using the new account.

Comment: i still cant understand how to delete old repo,canyou tell detail,include the command order,thank you

Comment: @winterbourne No deletion. Go to the old repo, and push to the new one.

Comment: it cant work       .it cant work       .it cant work       .it cant work       .it cant work       .it cant work       .

Comment: but why,i have cd old repo,and run the command

Comment: remote: Permission to nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git denied to jackey-xiong.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Forget it, as long as there is ssh, thank you

Comment: @winterbourne Because you have the credentials of the old account stored for github.com. See the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Context: Your old account was `jackey-xiong` and your repository belonged to that account. You have created a new account under the username `nathanielhawthorne`. A new repository is also created -> `https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git`. I am assuming this is an empty repo only at your remote now.

In your local, enter your springcloud repo. To see what is the upstream, you can jst do this command -> `git remote -v`

This will show you two urls like this.

```
origin  git@github.com:<user>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<user>/<repo_name>.git (push)
```

The first one is the remote address you pull changes from. Second one is the remote address when you push commits from your local to remote.

Ideally both will be the same. I am assuming that here also.

I think your remote right now will be pointing to your old account's repository address.

To change this and set it to your new repository's remote, use this command ->

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git
```

This will change your remote address.

Do a `git remote -v` to check if its changed correctly.

Note: All the commands writen here assume you are using ssh to communicate with git. If not change the addresses to https addresses. They will work the same.
If you are not using ssh,

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git
```

Comment: thankyou very much,by the one,Is the beginning of git@github my remote repository?

Comment: git@github signifies you are using ssh to communicate. It can also be a url like this -> `https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git`.

Comment: E:\Java Workspace\IDEA_Project\springcloud>git remote -v
springcloud     git@github.com:nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git (fetch)
springcloud     git@github.com:nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git (push)
springcloudie   https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/springcloud.git (fetch)

Comment: But all my content can only be transferred to the remote repository starting with git@github, https is not working

Comment: Let me replace the original remote repository and try again

Comment: If you are using https, git will try to authenticate using a username and password. This will exist in your gitconfig. See if you have updated them.  If you want to continue to use https, update your local gitconfig to properly authenticate your new account. If you want to use ssh, setup ssh-keys in your new account.

Comment: i want to use both ssh and https,how to update gitconfig?

Comment: My ssh upload is normal now, that is, https always points to the previous account

Comment: remote: Permission to nathanielhawthorne/test03.git denied to jackey-xiong.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nathanielhawthorne/test03.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: https still points to the original account